# How to Modify static buffer size for my ink smart contract to Resolving 'OutputBufferTooSmall' Error for Larger Vectors in ink smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, rust, pallet-contracts

I'm facing an 'OutputBufferTooSmall' error in my [Language/Framework] code when working with larger vectors. I suspect this is related to the maximum allowed input/output sizes. I need guidance on how to increase these limits to handle larger data. I also noticed that this issue has been addressed and resolved by the Ink team in this [GitHub PR](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1869) . Can someone help me understand how to implement these changes in my smart contract, or do I need to add an .env file to my contract folder?

Comment: I see this is an option in ink 5.0-rc but I have not figured out how to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Static Buffer is set at compile time. Do a cargo clean first and then compile like this (example is for 2MB):

```
INK_STATIC_BUFFER_SIZE=2000000 cargo contract build --release
```

See more here: https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/static-buffer/README.md

Also see this discussion when considering reasonable limits on your static buffer for off-chain contracts: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1471#issuecomment-1674781007